# how to enable gvt-g on the 4.17 kernel for centos7.5

Tags: gpu, kernel, centos-7

https://github.com/intel/gvt-linux/w...Tg_Setup_Guide

I follow this article to do

ubuntu 18.04 make install new kernel enable gvt-g is good,

but rhel7.5 or cenots7.5 can not work

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Need a lot of work for that.
The kernel version should support kvmgt module.
The ELRepo-kernel could match this.
But I never tested it.

You can try the latest version of proxmox.
Just a simple command `modprobe kvmgt` would enable GVT-g.

Hope you will feel happy with it. :)